# CSS - Top to Logo = 0px

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working for a few hours right now on the CSS changes on one of my customer´s website. My customer wants the header image (logo) to appear at the top of the screen without a space between the top and the logo.

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="avada-row" style="padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:0px; overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="logo" data-margin-right="0px" data-margin-left="0px" data-margin-top="3px" data-margin-bottom="3px" style="margin-right:0px;margin-top:3px;margin-left:0px;margin-bottom:3px;">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x100" alt="Heider Matriken – Falk Fengler" class="normal_logo">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I do not find the correct .css settings to solve this problem and to move the header image to the top. I already tried:

```
margin-top: -30px;
```

...but that is not working. It is a Wordpress Site, I am using Avada and the only thing I need is the header image at the top.

Would be cool if someone can help me out.

Comment: Div with class `avada-row` has inline-style with padding-top. Remove that

Comment: This should help: `.avada-row { padding: 0 !important; } .avada-row .logo { margin:0 !important; }`. Used **!important** because inline styling can't get overriden with specificity.

Comment: That´s it! Thank you emmanuel :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your generated code contains `padding-top:30px` in:

```
<div class="avada-row" style="padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:0px; overflow:hidden;">
```

I understand that you cannot change this, and a simple CSS won't help you because the inline style is more important.

Use [this trick](http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/) to override the inline style using an external CSS:

```
.avada-row {
    padding-top:0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tha class ".avada-row" is top padded, so you need to remove that padding:

```
.avada-row { padding-top: 0px !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

either use this HTML

```
<header id="header">
  <div style="padding-bottom:0px; overflow:hidden;" class="avada-row">
    <div style="margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-bottom:3px;" class="logo" data-margin-right="0px" data-margin-left="0px" data-margin-bottom="3px">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x100" alt="Heider Matriken – Falk Fengler" class="normal_logo">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

or use this css

```
.avada-row {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}
.avada-row .logo {
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```